# Proving $x^3 + 2x + 1$ is injective

Tags: functions, polynomials, proof-writing

So to prove a function is injective we assume that: $$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z},~f(x) = f(y) \to x = y$$

So this is what I've done thus far: $$x^{3} + 2x + 1 = y^{3} + 2y + 1$$ subtract 1 and factor $$x(x^{2} + 2) = y(y^{2} + 2)$$ and I know I want to show that $x = y$ and to do that here it seems I need to show the other factors are equivalent so that they vanish and I'm left with just $x = y$.

I just noticed that these factors $x^{2} + 2$ and $y^{2} + 2$ are $f'(x)$ and $f'(y)$ respectively. Could we say something like since we assume the functions are equal $(f(x) = f(y))$ then it follows that the derivatives are equivalent ($f'(x) = f'(y))$? Given that the function is continuous and smooth, of course.

Comment: Since the post implies you know derivatives, it's enough to note that $f'(x)=3x^2+2 \gt 0$ which means that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, thus injective. `noticed that these factors x^2+2 and y^2+2 are f′(x) and f′(y) respectively` No, you are missing a factor of $3$ for the squares.

Comment: The function $f$ is the sum of (strictly) increasing functions hence increasing.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your insight here. Also thanks @dxiv for the catch there -- slipped my mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have: $f(x) = f(y) \implies x^3+2x + 1 = y^3 + 2y+ 1\implies (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2 + 2)=0$. But $x^2+xy+y^2 + 2  = \left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+ \dfrac{3y^2}{4} + 2 > 0\implies x = y \implies $ one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

The function is monotone increasing, and thus injective.

Comment: What did you downvote this for ? Brevity ?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I'm not sure who did or their motivation. I thought your answer was clear and concise. If I didn't know what monotone increasing meant I'd just look it up and it would become evident. I see no fault. Thanks for your response!

Comment: +1 Compensatory upvote for what seems like a reasonable answer (and the one I would have given had you not already done so).

Comment: I was just trying to provide an alternative method.